# Vaadin Multiple Route With Same Component

Tags: view, routes, vaadin, instance

In my application I have tow screens with two modes. Create & View. Create is a form style one and view is a tabular(Grid in new flow component). Since the two pages have the view page in same format, I created a generic page and assigning routes dynamically on the view icon click. But issue is that it renders the first page always. I suspect, new instance of the view is not being generated.

The View Icon
[image]

This is the view rendered while clicking on CurrencyMenu View icon
[image]

This is the view rendered while clicking on Country Menu View icon
[image]

As you can see the views are the same. I am dynamically assigning routes at time of adding the tab.

```
RouteConfiguration.forSessionScope().setRoute(routeURL + "/" + RouteNames.ROUTE_VIEW, ViewPageUI.class, MainView.class);
```

I wanted to render the same page with different data for multiple routes. In other words, multiple instances of view page.(As per my understanding).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is two views that extend from a common super class. Then you can define the routes using `@Route` on the classes instead of adding dynamic routing when you do not really need it (less complexity is always better)

Comment: The super class concept also end up in the same problem. All the views gets overriden by last opened route data.

Comment: Then some more information or a code example is needed